# Is Unity NGUI still that usable after Unity has add support for 2D?

Tags: unity, ngui

I am tempted to refactor out the existing component which uses NGUI ("Next-Gen UI kit") given that what I needed is only the sprite and texture atlas.

Since in the newer versions of Unity those parts are natively supported, is there any reason I should still keep NGUI?

Comment: <nitpick about title> It's perfectly usable, but how *necessary* is a different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are referring to the new GUI system available in the 4.6 beta.

If you are already using NGUI on a project I would recommend you just stick with it. While Lyashenko (NGUI creator) did work on UGUI system during his brief stint as a Unity employee the two systems are not identical. Currently there may be a few features NGUI has that may be worth keeping it around for.

If you are considering which to go with for a new project, the biggest factor is that 4.6 is still technically a beta release. While it seems pretty stable, doing production work on beta software is always a risk and we don't know when it is going to leave beta.

Comment: Just want to say that 4.6 is no longer a beta. The question needs a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unity 4.6 is in beta. Which means, other than possibility that certain features may change at final release, you cannot publish anything with it. A simple web build generated in beta will run only on the computer it was generated on.

Comment: And , 4.6 has been in beta for a few months and we don't have a final launch date yet. It might be months before it is out of beta.